# Change dialog button color (Next/Back) : Intro JS React

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, intro.js

I am using a React wrapper for [intro js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/intro.js-react),
and I am trying to change the default background color for dialog buttons.

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/o2A4gwXE3?hidenavigation=1) given in the documentation
I want to change the background color of the Next button here [image: Default Next Button]

I have been trying to look this up all over the web but I cannot find a solution.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had to inspect the element and override the CSS to make it work.
[image: Inspect the css class]

Then the color got changed correctly
[image: Color changed]

Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67566764/9977815